# Conditional probability formulas

Tags: probability

I'm reading notes about conditional probability.

Now the first formula is:

$$Pr(\omega \mid B) = \frac{Pr(\omega)}{Pr(B)} \text{ where } \omega \in B$$

The next formula is:

$$Pr(A\mid B) = \frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$$

Isn't it two different definitions?

Also, can you please demonstrate the formula on: What are the chances to get the result $4$ from a regular dice, given the result is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the first formula is a special case of the second. Let $A=\{ω\}\in B$ and $B=B$, then if you substitute in the second formula, you obtain that $$Pr(ω\mid B)=Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}=\frac{P(\{ω\}\cap B)}{Pr(B)}\overset{ω\in B}=\frac{Pr(\{ω\})}{Pr(B)}$$ as the first formula states.

Comment: Thank you. What would be $Pr(\text{result is 4}\cap\text{result is even})$? (For a dice role). Is it $\frac{1}{6}$?

Comment: @AlonAlon Result of what? You should be more specific. But in general 4 is even... so do you see a connection with the above?

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a special case of the second definition.
As far as I can see, the second definition **does not** follows from the first.

It is highly customary to accept the second as the definition.

Answer (score 1):

If $\omega \in B$, then $\{\omega\} \cap B = \{\omega\}$.

Comment: Yes, this is sloppy and imprecise. I should use $\{\omega\}$.